# Module loaded in setupFilesAfterEnv is not mockable any more

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I want to initialise some module in `setupFilesAfterEnv` in Jest runner for all tests and I want also test this file by mocking its imports in a single test file only, but since Jest v29 it did not succeed any more.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a module:

   `foo.ts`:

   ```
    import NavigationService from './navigation.service';

    // init something here
    // initSomethingGlobally();

    export const foo = () => {
      NavigationService.navigate({bar: true});
    };
   ```

   `navigation.service.ts`:

   ```
    function navigate(action?: Record<string, any>) {
      console.log('Navigating to ' + JSON.stringify(action));
    }
    const NavigationService = {
      navigate,
    };
    export default NavigationService;
   ```
2. Create a `setupFilesAfterEnv` that imports a module you want to test (here foo):

   `setupFilesAfterEnv.ts`:

   ```
    import './src/foo';
   ```

   and add this file to Jest config:

   ```
        "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
          "./jest/setupAfterEnv.ts"
        ]
   ```
3. Create a test:

   `foo-test.ts`:

   ```
    import NavigationService from '../navigation.service';
    import {foo} from '../foo';

    jest.mock('../navigation/navigation.service');

    describe('foo', () => {
      it('should spy NavigationService.navigate call', () => {
        foo();
        expect(NavigationService.navigate).toHaveBeenCalledWith({bar: true});
      });
    });
   ```

Expected behavior: module should be mockable even if it was called in `setupFilesAfterEnv` before.

Actual behavior: mock is not used, test fails with error (as not called):

```
Expected: {"bar": true}

Number of calls: 0
```

This behavior works in Jest v27.

If I remove `setupFilesAfterEnv` import, its works as expected.

Environment

```
System:
    OS: macOS 13.6
    CPU: (8) arm64 Apple M1
  Binaries:
    Node: 18.18.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.0/bin/node
    Yarn: 1.22.19 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.0/bin/yarn
    npm: 10.1.0 - ~/.nvm/versions/node/v18.18.0/bin/npm
```

Related (autoclosed) issue: [`jestjs/jest#14618`](https://github.com/jestjs/jest/issues/14618).

Any ideas?